# Why doesn't seem create project link in web app after installing teamcity?

Tags: continuous-integration, teamcity

i installed teamcity in [here](http://www.jetbrains.com/teamcity/download/index.html)
but i don't see "create project" link in team city web app.

see this text
"There are no projects in TeamCity. Please contact your system administrator."

Comment: You should see "Administration" link in the top right corner of the web app. Just go there and create a project.

Comment: Unfortuantely i don't see "Administaration" link

Comment: Try to log out and login as admin user. You're probably logged in as a "Guest"